# How do I un-hide tools in WSCC

Tags: windows, wscc

So, I was tooling around in [Windows System Control Center](http://www.kls-soft.com/wscc/index.php) today, and I tried using the "Don't show in the list" option on some of the tools that I don't often use.

However, I also started to consider what I'd need to do if I ever *needed* one of those programs again.  Obviously, I could just go out to the proper source site and download the program as a stand-alone.  But, I'd rather keep it all under WSCC where they can all be easily found and updated.

However, I've dug around all the screens now, and can't find any indicator of the programs I'd hidden.  Is there a way to un-hide these without having to re-install the whole thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you right-click inside the WSCC window, you can enable **Show Hidden Items**:

[image]

Alternatively, you can control the behavior through the Options:

[image]

Comment: Wow.  Right in front of me the whole time.  Ouch.